# Error: Command failed: gm convert pdf-image conversion

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick, pdf-conversion

I am trying to convert pdf to images in node.js app. For that I am using `pdf-image` npm module.

I googled it and installed `pdf-image` npm module and `graphicsmagick` using `apt-get install graphicsmagick` in linux os.

```
let pdfImage = new PDFImage("./file.pdf",{graphicsMagick: true,convertOptions: {
            "-resize": "2000x2000",
            "-quality": "75"
          }}); 
        pdfImage.convertFile().then((imagePaths)=>{
            console.log(imagePaths)
            cb(null,imagePaths)
        },(err)=>{
            cb(err)
        });
```

In my local system its working fine and perfect.
But when I deployed this to my `AWS ec2` instance  and installed all required libraries but its throwing error

```
gm convert: Coder did not return an image (this is a bug, please report it!)
```

I am doing the same as local in ec2 instance but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install ImageMagick Ghostscript poppler-utils

In

> /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml (or /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml)

find the following line

and change it to allow reading and writing by the PDF coder in ImageMagick:

if use this sudo service php7.2-fpm restart require to  restart

Answer (score 0):

Solved similar problem in Rails framework by changing `cli` to imagemagick (was `graphicsmagick` that was the cause of the error)

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.cli = :imagemagick # or :graphicsmagick or :imagemagick7
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/minimagick/minimagick